# Perpendicular chord lengths from the boundary points of an arbitary 2D shape

Tags: random, geometry, distance, discretization

Let's generate an arbitrary convex domain with smooth boundaries:

```
Graphics[BSplineCurve[{{1, 4}, {5, 3}, {9, 4}, {5, 5}, {8, 7}}, 
  SplineClosed -> True]]
```

[image]

I'd like to discretize the boundary and calculate the **perpendicular distances from each point to the corresponding points across** the boundary of the domain. Like in the following picture:

[image]

At first I thought it should be simple but after some time I couldn't come up with a proper solution. How would you do that? I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: are the curves always parametric (as opposed to implicit) ?

Comment: No, it can be implicit as well. I used parametric points just for the representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bsf = BSplineFunction[{{1, 4}, {5, 3}, {9, 4}, {5, 5}, {8, 7}}, SplineClosed -> True]; 
line = Cases[ParametricPlot[bsf[t], {t, 0, 1}] [[1]], _Line, All][[1]]; 

mesh = Range[0, 1, .1];
coords = Nearest[RegionIntersection[line, 
       InfiniteLine[{bsf[#], (bsf[#] + Cross[bsf'[#]])}]][[1]]][bsf[#], 2] & /@ mesh; 

ParametricPlot[bsf[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 1, AspectRatio -> 1,
 Epilog -> {Arrowheads[.03], {RandomColor[], Dynamic@
  Text[Style[Round[#[[1]], .1], 14, Darker@CurrentValue["Color"]],
     #[[1]], {-1.2, 0}, Subtract@@#],
  PointSize[Large], Point[#[[1]]], Thick, Arrow@#} & /@ coords}]
```

[image]

Note: This is too slow to work interactively.